# Autodesk Forge Viewer place point from external database

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to place a geometry/point to a specific element, to add note or comment.n.g to the select element

I a using `viewer.getSelection()` get the element `dbid`, my idea is if I can store all the dbIds to an external database. I am still struggling how to place the point to the 3d/2d viewer and load it with the 3d/2d viewer every time?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I do pretty much the same thing in this demo: https://forge-digital-twin.autodesk.io, allowing users to click on a specific design element and attach an "issue" to it. For each issue I store the element's dbID as well as the actual XYZ coordinate on the surface of the object that the user clicked. And then I use this [viewer extension](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-digital-twin/blob/master/public/scripts/extensions/issues.js) to display the issues on the model (and have them stick to the right place even when I orbit/zoom the camera or explode the model).